# Скрытие ActionBar при прокручивании списков в табах

Tags: android, listview

Есть проект, сделанный по такому примеру: [github](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Google-Play-Style-Tabs-using-TabLayout).

Только фрагменты отдельными файлами со своей разметкой. Во вкладках находится `ListView`.

Как сделать, чтобы при прокрутке `ActionBar` убирался и оставались только табы?

В гугле нашем много примеров этого, но они все немного сложноваты. Может, кто объяснить, как это сделать? Желательно коротко (например: добавить то-то туда-то, ещё что-то ещё куда-то...)

Делаю так

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/viewpager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#730600"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

ToolBar и Tab вообще не отображаются, только viewpager

Comment: Ссылка из ответа: [How to hide/show Toolbar when list is scrolling](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling(part2)/)

Comment: С появлением библиотеки поддержки *support:design* и контейнеров `CoordinatorLayout`,`AppBarLayout` пример из комментария выше потерял свою актуальность ввиду излишней сложности реализации.

Comment: Т.е это можно реализовать в разметке, без кода?

Answer (score 2):

Вам надо:

1. Библиотека `design-support-library` ([eng](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html), [рус](http://www.fandroid.info/android-design-support-library-podderzhka-komponentov-material-design-v-prilozheniyah-s-android-2-1-do-android-5-s-primerami/))
2. `CoordinatorLayout`
3. В `CoordinatorLayout` - `AppBarLayout` и любой контейнер для основного содержимого экрана (например `FrameLayout`)
4. В `AppBarLayout` - `Toolbar` и `TabLayout`
5. `Toolbar`-у и `TabLayout`-у надо назначить `app:layout_scrollFlags="тут поэсперементировать"`

Comment: У меня подчёркивает app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"

Comment: @user186301, убедитесь, что вы указали пространство имён в атрибутах корневого элемента разметки `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"`